# Slideshow Flexslider is too fast

Tags: flexslider

I am using a flexslider slideshow on my website and it is too fast. I would like it to pause between each slide. There are 3 slides. It is not easy read all the text on one of the slides before another slide shows up.

The below code is from the Functions.js file. How can I slow down the slide and let it pause between each slide.

---

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlsContainer: ".slider-holder",
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: true,
        animationDuration: 5000,
        before:function( slider ){
            $('.img-holder').animate({'bottom' : '-30px'},300)
        },

        after:function( slider ){
            $('.img-holder').animate({'bottom' : '0px'},300)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlsContainer: ".slider-holder",
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: true,          
        animationSpeed: 6000,
        before:function( slider ){
            $('.img-holder').animate({'bottom' : '-30px'},300)
        },

        after:function( slider ){
            $('.img-holder').animate({'bottom' : '0px'},300)
        }
    });
});
```

use `animationSpeed: 6000` option control the speed,value is in `millseconds` 6000=6 seconds,also remove `animationDuration` ,there is no such option